# Creating the turtlesim environment through code

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlesim, ros-tutorials, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.  I've just started using ROS yesterday - i've completed the 15 or so beginner tutorials that utilize turtlesim.  I've begun writing my own .cpp file - since i'm a beginner this is all pretty new to me.  I'm trying to figure out how to create the actual turtlesim simulator window from C++ code.  This sounds like it would be easy so can anyone help? I've been looking at several of the files in the documentation but there isn't a real clear answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12783/creating-the-turtlesim-environment-through-code./) by [Index](https://answers.ros.org/users/1702/index/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlesim window is a separate executable. Typically, C++ does not support running executable from code. Typically you have to use the `system()` command to do so. But, there is also a system called [rosspawn](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosspawn) that might just do what you want it to do.

I'm not sure what the end goal is, but there are a couple of options I can think of:

If you're trying to launch turtlesim at the same time as one of your own executables, I would suggest [roslaunch](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch).

If you're looking to do something that you cannot do via turtlesim's topics and services, I would suggest looking at the code for turtlesim in the turtlesim package (probably in the `src` directory). You might be able to modify it to your needs.

If you edit your question to be more specific as to the goal, I might be able to help further.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-27**:
I would start a new question for that so that others can benefit from it.

**Comment by [Index](https://answers.ros.org/users/1702/index/) on 2012-01-27**:
Thanks, using a launch file and roslaunch worked!  I just want to learn the basics and build from there - I am a beginner after all.  After looking at the sample source .cpp files, there doesn't seem to be a clear way to just simply move the robot forward or turn - can you help me with that?